# How to get the user authentication in Splash Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a small app that has a Splash Screen and a User Login.

I want to launch different tab menu based on the user's ID.

Let say I have an Admin who has ID == "100" will get AdminTabActivity and rest of others will get UserTabActivity. so I wrote it like this. I'm simply passing the user ID from here to the MainActivity.

SplashActivity.java

```
public void run(){
        try{
        sleep(1000);
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);  
            finish();

        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {                                  

        }
    }
```

LoginActivity.java

```
//Stores and Grabs the user ID from sqlite db
db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_ID), 
           json_user.getString(KEY_NAME));                                                 

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);                 

    i.putExtra(KEY_ID, id);
    startActivity(i);

    finish();
```

MainActivity.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String id = i.getStringExtra(KEY_ID);

if("001".equals(id)){

    /* Launch Admin Screen if ID == 100 */

    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminTabActivity.class);           
    startActivity(in);          
    finish();

}else{

    /* Launch User Screen if ID !== 100 */

    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserTabActivity.class);                        
    startActivity(in);      
    finish();

}
```

If the user exits out of the app and returns back, it will skips the LoginActivity and go straight from Splash to MainActivity (which I want it to be), but the **if block** will skip this time even if the user has the ID == "100". Hope it makes sense, if not please kindly let me know so I can explain more. Thank you!

Comment: so what you want is you have 2 type of splash screen?I'm sorry but I'm still didn't get your concept

Comment: Hi Nana.  You're focusing too much on the code and not *what* you are trying to do.  Edit your question (there's an edit link at the bottom), remove everything and then write down what you are trying to do, why you are trying to do it and what you are having a problem with and take time to ensure it is accurate. Read the two sentences under the MainActivity.java above.  I've read them several times and I still don't get it.  Learning how to create good questions is even more important than learning how to give good answers since you can never get a good answer to a bad question.

Comment: @Simon, How are you? thank you for your kindly advice. I'm really trying to explain my problem but I must not know the right words to explain in java or android. I will try to edit it again. Thank you again for patient and your kindness.

Comment: I'm fine thank you.  I hope that you are too, and this time, I think I understand your question.  I just have one question left.  Will this be the same person logging in as different "roles" or will it be multiple people using your app?  If multiple people, is it on one device?  So multiple people using the same app on a single device?

Comment: there are multiple users using the same app with their own devices.